# cmake doesn't generate Qt moc files using QT4_automoc

Tags: qt4, cmake, moc

I'm trying to compile a little test application [basic layout example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/layouts-basiclayouts.html) in Qt using the Visual Studio 2010 compiler on Windows 7.

I'm using cmake (2.8.4) and nmake to build the example, but it fails to generate moc files.
This leads to a compilation error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'dialog.moc': No such file or directory.
```

The rules in my CMakeLists.txt which should enable generation of the moc files are:

```
set(all_SOURCES main.cpp dialog.cpp)
QT4_AUTOMOC(${all_SOURCES})
```

Any ideas why no moc files are generated or tips to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Collect all the headers you need a moc of pass those headers to qt4_wrap_cpp and than add out those files to your library/executable.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
set (FOO_MOC_HEADERS foo.h)
qt4_wrap_cpp (FOO_MOC_OUTFILES ${FOO_MOC_HEADERS})
add_library (foo SHARED ${FOO_SOURCE_FILES} ${FOO_MOC_OUTFILES})
```

Comment: Somehow (even though I tried it several times) it does seem to work now with qt4_automoc, using 
set(all_SOURCES main.cpp dialog.cpp)
QT4_AUTOMOC(${all_SOURCES})
add_executable(Test ${all_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Test ${LINK_LIBRARIES})

Comment: I think you should prefer qt4_wrap_cpp, adding the output of that to your library rather than manually including the .moc files. I have found that to be more reliable in the past.